Unable to create VLAN on top of vbond
I am using CPU
Model name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU D-1581 @ 1.80GHz
with two 10G NIC's
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection X552 10 GbE Backplane
02:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection X552 10 GbE Backplane
On top of these PF, I created VF's. By taking one VF from each PF, I further created vbond. This is stated in screenshot below. I deliberately down the eno1 interface from the switch.
$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
4: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8954 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: vbond: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,ALLMULTI,PROMISC,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    vf 0 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking off, link-state auto, trust on, query_rss off
    vf 1 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking off, link-state auto, trust on, query_rss off
    vf 2 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking off, link-state auto, trust on, query_rss off
    vf 3 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking off, link-state auto, trust on, query_rss off
    vf 4 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking off, link-state auto, trust on, query_rss off
    vf 5 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking off, link-state auto, trust on, query_rss off
    vf 6 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking off, link-state auto, trust on, query_rss off
    vf 7 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking off, link-state auto, trust on, query_rss off
    vf 8 MAC 06:00:00:7f:02:2a, spoof checking off, link-state auto, trust on, query_rss off
7: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,ALLMULTI,PROMISC,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8954 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    vf 0 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking off, link-state auto, trust on, query_rss off
    vf 1 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking off, link-state auto, trust on, query_rss off
    vf 2 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking off, link-state auto, trust on, query_rss off
    vf 3 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking off, link-state auto, trust on, query_rss off
    vf 4 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking off, link-state auto, trust on, query_rss off
    vf 5 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking off, link-state auto, trust on, query_rss off
    vf 6 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking off, link-state auto, trust on, query_rss off
    vf 7 MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00, spoof checking off, link-state auto, trust on, query_rss off
    vf 8 MAC 06:00:00:7f:02:2a, spoof checking off, link-state auto, trust on, query_rss off
16: vnic1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master vbond state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
25: vnic2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master vbond state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Problem:
The issue here is when I tried to create the vlan on top of bond0, it works fine. But if I try to execute the same command for vbond, it fails.
$ sudo ip link add link bond0 name vbond.10 type vlan id 10
[sudo] password for admin:
$ sudo ip link add link vbond name vbond.11 type vlan id 11
RTNETLINK answers: Permission denied

If i just flip it and make the eno1 UP and eno2 DOWN, then vlan command for both interfaces, bond0 and vbond works fine.
Below are the configuration for vbond
cat /proc/net/bonding/vbond
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)
Bonding Mode: fault-tolerance (active-backup)
Primary Slave: vnic1 (primary_reselect always)
Currently Active Slave: vnic2
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 10
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: vnic1
MII Status: down
Speed: Unknown
Duplex: Unknown
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: vnic2
MII Status: up
Speed: 10000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 1
Permanent HW addr: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Slave queue ID: 0


This is for bond0
cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
enter code here
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: fault-tolerance (active-backup)
Primary Slave: None
Currently Active Slave: eno2
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 10
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: eno2
MII Status: up
Speed: 10000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 2
Permanent HW addr: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Slave queue ID: 0

Any help, why this is not working or any pointer or reference?
